# sort an array of objects by 1 or more property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am figuring out if there is a better way to sort the below array.

The below code sorts the array based on the label and deviceRegistered.
if label is Desk phone and deviceRegistered is true then it should take the precedence.

My approach is like below.

```
const terminals = [
  {
    "device":"JKJCF00",
    "directory":"+1899990000",
    "label":"Jabber",
    "deviceRegistered":"false"
  },
  {
    "device":"IOP8999",
    "directory":"9099886644",
    "label":"Desk Phone",
    "deviceRegistered":"false"
  }, 
  {
    "device":"KLJ7888",
    "directory":"+8999999",
    "label":"Jabber",
    "deviceRegistered":"true"
  },  
  {
    "device":"VFD87987",
    "directory":"+12386444",
    "label":"Desk Phone",
    "deviceRegistered":"true"
  }]
```

```
let term = [...terminals],arr=[],sortedLines = [],lineObj ={};
  term.forEach(line => arr.indexOf(line.label)===-1 ? arr.push(line.label):'');
  arr.forEach(device => {
     let filterArr = term.filter(line => line.label === device)
     let sortArr = [...filterArr].sort((dev1,dev2) => dev1.deviceRegistered !== 'true' ? 1 : dev2.deviceRegistered !== 'true' ? -1 : 0)
     lineObj[device] = sortArr
  })
  for (line in lineObj){ console.log(lineObj[line])
     sortedLines.push(...lineObj[line])
  }
}
```

The output is

```
[
  {
    "device":"KLJ7888",
    "directory":"+8999999",
    "label":"Jabber",
    "deviceRegistered":"true"
  },
  {
    "device":"JKJCF00",
    "directory":"+1899990000",
    "label":"Jabber",
    "deviceRegistered":"false"
  },
  {
    "device":"VFD87987",
    "directory":"+12386444",
    "label":"Desk Phone",
    "deviceRegistered":"true"
  },
  {
    "device":"IOP8999",
    "directory":"9099886644",
    "label":"Desk Phone",
    "deviceRegistered":"false"
  }
]
```

Comment: @Barmar mybad ... haven't seen that

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the properties and use the delta of the boolean values.

```js
const
    array = [
        { device: "JKJCF00", directory: "+1899990000", label: "Jabber", deviceRegistered: "false" },
        { device: "IOP8999", directory: "9099886644", label: "Desk Phone", deviceRegistered: "false" },
        { device: "KLJ7888", directory: "+8999999", label: "Jabber", deviceRegistered: "true" },
        { device: "VFD87987", directory: "+12386444", label: "Desk Phone", deviceRegistered: "true" }
    ];
    
array.sort((a, b) =>
    (b.label === 'Desk Phone') - (a.label === 'Desk Phone') ||
    (b.deviceRegistered === 'true') - (a.deviceRegistered === 'true')
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, That was a one liner code. I am trying to figure out your solution. Would appreciate if you can  explain that comparison.

Comment: Got it. Your title 'You could check the properties and use the delta of the boolean values.' explains  it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: I'm the author of this library, but I created sort-es exactly to simplify the array sorting.

If you're interested : [docs](https://sort-es.netlify.app/) [GH](https://github.com/cosimochellini/sort-es)

```
import { byValues, byString, byValue, byBoolean } from "sort-es"

const terminals = [] //...items

const sorted = terminals.sort(byValues([
    ["label", byString()],
    ["deviceRegistered", byValue(d => d === 'true', byBoolean())]
]))
```